# Understanding and avoiding the dangers of nested locks in multithreaded applications

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am still fairly new to multithreading but got already burnt several times.
Now I try to avoid some pitfalls but I have a hard time with the following:

Consider several threads, Thread `A` Producer, hence `writer`, Thread `B`, `C`,... Consumer threads hence `reader`.
All share a common buffer `S`

Some basic books propose to introduce a so called `ReadWriteLock` for this scenario.
Multiple concurrent reads are possible but obviously only one write.Boost offers such locks, Qt as well.

Lets assume two functions f1 and f2 that lock S for reading. 
In Thread `B` f1 is called and locks for reading and f2 is called inside f1 and locks for reading again, hence **nested locking** is possible.

Now consider the instant when f1 is executed and locks for read for the first time. If thread A gets called and wants to write he gets blocked.
Further if inside f1 f2 gets called and wants to lock it can’t since a blocked `writer` is waiting and in this case many locks (e.g. `QReadWriteLock`) block further `readers` as well. 
Hence we get a very nasty deadlock that is non-predictable and occurs only if a `writer` kicks in between the lock in f1 and the lock of f2.

My current approach to avoid such bugs is a debug tool that tracks locking and asserts if the same thread tries to lock for read twice, but this is quite cumbersome.
Apart from this I avoid putting much code inside a lock, which helps but can be ignored by other members of my team.

What other functionality can be used to prevent such scenarios ? 
Why do ReadWriteLocks permit them at all ?
Are there some general rules of thumb to avoid the above scenario in the design phase?

Thanks in advance for reading the long question ;-)

Comment: The multiple-reader-single-writer lock should not count a single recursive lock as "multiple", I think...

Comment: Good point, but the nasty beast QReadWriteLock does, which just cost me 3 hours of debugging %-&

Comment: @Kerrek: I just gave an Option QReadWriteLock::Recursive a try and this way it seems to work but the description in the manpages is more than unclear to me:  
"QReadWriteLock::Recursive In this mode, a thread can lock the same QReadWriteLock multiple times and the mutex won't be unlocked until a corresponding number of unlock() calls have been made.
QReadWriteLock::NonRecursive: In this mode, a thread may only lock a QReadWriteLock once." Nothing about the consequences if the default:NonRecursive is used and even then multiple readlocking from the same thread is possible

Comment: Well, for *any* sort of lock it is *your* responsibility to ensure that any given thread doesn't attempt to obtain the lock more than once, or otherwise specifically request a recursive lock. I don't know Qt, but it's unsurprising that you'd need to ask for this explicitly...

Comment: The products passed between the producer and consumers, are they expensive to copy?

Comment: Depends on the point of view: approymately 10 doubles per sample, 200 samples per second in the buffer, approximately 10 readers that evaluate the data ion real-time and do calculations. Several buffers like this one. The whole code has to run on a 600mHz Smartphone core. I'm still wondering whether simple copies might not do the trick as well

Comment: Several buffers?  If there are several buffers, can you queue them to a pool of threads so that there is no sharing of the buffers?

Comment: @Martin: Do you mean that the data is processed in 200-sample chunks? And these chunks are what is passed around from producer to consumers? Does the data processed by the consumers have to be recombined somehow, or are the consumers running more or less independently from each other? If you could sketch out a rough dataflow diagram of your application (it can be ASCII art or words), we might be able to suggest a different approach to what you are doing.

Comment: These are pretty standard headaches when writing threaded code.  You'll learn to not get fancy when holding a lock.  Grab it, copy, release it.  Wham bam, good for concurrency as well.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use tryReadLock function from QReadWriteLock. to prevent a dead lock.

if it failed to lock for read.. then unlock the read mutex.

in several cases, it can loss a data to read, if you dont want to loss any data to read,it can be solve by put a flag or ID number or something to identify your failed read jobs and put it into a stack so after write thread finish doing his job, you will be able to resume your read things start with a failed one. it will minimize you to loss data..

i hope it will help.

sory for my bad english.